# Summing a trigonometric series, $\sum\limits_{n＝1}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin nx}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin nx}{n}}$$
I tried $(\frac{\sin nx}n)'＝\cos nx$，then
consider $\;\sum\limits_{n＝1}^\infty\cos nx\;$ , but I didn't succeed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem...?

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71706/using-fourier-series-to-calculate-an-infinite-sum or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514850/compute-infinite-sum-using-fourier-series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin nx}n}=$ imaginary part of $\displaystyle\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(e^{ix})^n}n$

$\displaystyle-\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(e^{ix})^n}n=\ln(1-e^{ix})$

$\displaystyle=\ln(e^{ix/2})+\ln(-1)+\ln(e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2})$

$\displaystyle=ix/2+\ln(-i)+\ln(2\sin x/2)$

$\displaystyle=ix/2-i\pi/2+\ln(2\sin x/2)$

as $e^{(4m-1)i\pi/2}=-i$ for some integer $m$

the principal value of $\ln(-i)=-\dfrac{i\pi}2$

Comment: If "$m$ is any integer" then aren't you saying the sum has infinitely many different values?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Complex_argument

Comment: I know about principal values, but you have $\sum n^{-1}\sin nx=x/2+(4m-1)\pi/2$, where $m$ is any integer. Can that be right?

Comment: You should justify why the principal branch of log is the right choice. (e.g. using  something like [Abel's theorem for power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem))

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\log(1-z) =- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$$

where $z = e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n}=\textrm{Im} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n} \right)=\textrm{Im} \left( - \log(1-z)  \right).$$

$\textrm{Im}(z)$ stands for the Imaginary part of the complex number $z$ as usual.

Comment: And how does $x$ relate to $z$?

Comment: $z^n=e^{nix}=\cos nx + i \sin nx.$

Comment: In other words, $z=e^{ix}$, right?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879726/evaluation-of-sum-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nn/3319218#3319218

Answer (score 0):

my attemp:

$$\   I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{sin(n)}{n}   \  \  \  \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)\\
\\
we\ know\ that: \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}\ \ \ ,|x|<1 \ \ \\
\\
\\
 let\ x=re^{i\theta }\ , \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ for \ \ \ all\ \ \ \ \ |r|<1\\
\\
\therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }r^{n}(cosn\theta +isin(n\theta ))=\frac{rcos\theta +irsin\theta }{(1-rcos\theta )-irsin\theta }\\
\\
\therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }r^{n-1}(cosn\theta +isinn\theta )=\frac{(cos\theta +isin\theta )(1-rcos\theta +irsin\theta )}{(1-rcos\theta )^2+r^2sin^2\theta }\\
\\
\therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }r^{n-1}sin(n\theta )=\frac{sin\theta }{r^2-2rcos\theta +1}\ \ \ \ \therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }sin(n\theta )\int_{0}^{1}r^{n-1}dr=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{sin\theta }{sin \theta ^ 2+(r-cos\theta )^2}dr\\
\\
 =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{sin\theta +sin\theta (\frac{r-cos\theta }{sin\theta })^2}dr=arctan(\frac{r-cos\theta }{sin\theta })\\
\\
\\
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{sin(n\theta )}{n}=arctan(\frac{1-cos\theta }{sin\theta })+arctan(\frac{1}{tan\theta })=arctantan\frac{\theta }{2}+\frac{\pi }{2}-\theta   \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \\ 
 now \ put\ \theta =1\\
\\
\\
\therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{sinn}{n}=\frac{\pi -1}{2}\\
\\
\\
$$