# show that, $\left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)^k=(k-1)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{kn}}{(2n+1)^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw this sum on a maths paper, it read "Sophomore's dream". I haven't got a clue what is mean, anyway this is the formula.

(1)
$$\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)^2=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Using experimental mathematics we was able to arrive at this formula, where k=2 gives (1)

Valid for $k\ge 2$

$$\left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)^k=(k-1)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{kn}}{(2n+1)^k}$$

Question 1,

How do you go about proving this formula?
We try the following steps...
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^k=(k-1)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{nk}}{(2n+1)^k}=\Gamma(k-1)\int_{-1}^1  \frac{(-\ln(x))^{k-1}}{1+x^2}dx$$.

Where $\Gamma(k)$ is the Gamma function is defined as $\Gamma(k)=(k-1)!$

**This is where I stop for help. I'm unable to evaluate this integral, can anybody help me, please ?**

Comment: For $k=3$ the rhs is 0, but the lhs is $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3$.

Comment: How is that possible?

Comment: The terms for -1,0 have equal magnitude and opposite sign. Similarly for -2,1 and -3,2 and so on.

Comment: You mean the sum becomes zero?

Comment: I mean that the result fails for $k=3$ and indeed for all odd $k$.

Comment: I just verify with my calculator numerically, k=3 is valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39265/discussion-between-pisquare-and-almagest).

Comment: You have now changed the formula to $(-1)^{kn}$, but it still doesn't work for odd $k$.

Comment: Dusplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-alternating-zeta-series