# $\prod_{p=3 mod 4}{\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}}$, $p$ is prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, products, constants, catalans-constant

It is known that the
$$\prod_{p}{\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}}=\frac{2}{5}$$
But there is a formula:
$$\prod_{p=3 \operatorname{mod} 4}{\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}}=\frac{8G}{\pi^2}$$
The $G$ is Catalan's constant.

Is last formula well known? Or is there any known relation of Catalan's constant and prime numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the Catalan constant and $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ are associated with $L(\chi,2)$ Dirichlet series:

$$ G = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)^2},\qquad \frac{\pi^2}{8}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2m+1)^2} $$
hence by denoting with $\chi_0$ and $\chi_1$ the principal and non-principal character $\!\!\pmod{4}$ we have
$$ G = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\chi_1(p)}{p^2}\right)^{-1},\qquad \frac{\pi^2}{8}=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\chi_0(p)}{p^2}\right)^{-1} $$
by Euler's product, such that
$$ \frac{8G}{\pi^2}=\prod_{p}\frac{p^2-\chi_0(p)}{p^2-\chi_1(p)} = \prod_{p\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{\!\!4}}\frac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}$$
as wanted. In a similar fashion
$$ \prod_{p\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{\!\!4}}\frac{p^3-1}{p^3+1}=\frac{\pi^3}{28\,\zeta(3)}$$
due to [a well-known identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas).