# On the approximation $\pi\approx 31^\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: reference-request, approximation, pi

The Mathworld page about approximations to $\pi$ indicates that **M. Joseph** communicated the approximation

$$\pi \approx 31^\frac{1}{3}$$

in 2006, which is listed as formula 43 in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiApproximations.html.

**Are there further references to this approximation or its author?**

Comment: I'm sure the values $\pi^2 \approx 9.87, \pi^3 \approx 31.006, \pi^4 \approx 97.409$ have been observed prior to 2006. Considering Ramanujan gave approximations for $\pi^4$, he must have known of the near-integer $\pi^3$ as well.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such approximation is a consequence of [a well-known identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas):
$$ \frac{\pi^3}{32} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^3} \tag{1}$$
The RHS of $(1)$ is a fast-convergent series and $32\sum_{n=0}^5 \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^3}\approx 31$, hence $\color{red}{\pi^3\approx 31}$.

---

In a similar fashion $\frac{5\pi^5}{1536}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^5}$ and $1536\sum_{n=0}^{6}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^5}\approx 1530+\frac{1}{10}$ lead to
$$ \pi^5 \approx \frac{15301}{50} \tag{2} $$
but I guess that $\pi\approx\left(\frac{15301}{50}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}$ is a less fascinating approximation than $\pi\approx 31^{1/3}$.

Comment: With a fifth root I like
$$\pi\approx 3+\frac{1}{17571^\frac{1}{5}}$$
Raymond Manzoni wrote it in a comment somewhere.

Comment: We can write an exact expression for the error as:
$$\pi^3 = 31 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 5\frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n + 1)^3} + 27\frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{(2 n + 3)^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the fact that  $\pi^3\approx 31.00628$. I doubt you will find a reference.

Comment: I guess that a well-known identity about Euler numbers is a valid reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas