# Does $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^k\left(\tan^2{x\over 2}\right)\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^k\left(\tan^2{x}\right)\mathrm dx$ hold only for even $k$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Why is it that apparently only for ***even*** $k$,

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^k\left(\tan^2{x\over 2}\right)\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^k\left(\tan^2{x}\right)\mathrm dx$$

Specificallly, for ***all*** $k$,

$$\text{LHS}=-(-2)^{k+1}k!\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^{k+1}}$$

But for ***odd*** $k$,

$$\text{RHS}=0$$

The case of $k=2$ for the $\text{LHS}$ is discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574409/an-interesting-integral-with-log-int-0-pi-2-ln2-left-tan2-leftx-ove), while the $\text{RHS}$ is in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503920/evaluate-2-int-0-pi-over-2-ln2-tan2x-mathrm-dx).

Comment: I only got [the result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate+from+0+to+Pi%2F2+Log%5BTan%5Bx%5D%5E2%5D%5E3) $\text{RHS}=0$ from _WA_, so I don't know how reliable that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$\tan^2 \left(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = \cot^2 x = \frac{1}{\tan^2 x},$$  it follows that $$\log^k \tan^2 \left(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = (-1)^k \log^k \tan^2 x,$$ hence when $k$ is positive odd, the integrand is antisymmetric about $x = \pi/4$.  When $k$ is positive even, the integrand is symmetric about $x = \pi/4$.