# Is it possible to express $\pi$ as $a^b$ for $a$ and $b$ non-transcendental numbers?

Tags: pi, transcendental-numbers

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611029/ls-sqrt2-sqrt3-the-only-sum-of-two-irrational-which-close-to-pi) I thought: the algebraic numbers are closed under the operations $+,\div,\times,-,\sqrt[n]{\cdot}$ for arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$.

However, as far as I know, they are not closed under exponentiation. Then my questions:

1. It is known if $\pi$ can be represented by $a^b$ for some algebraic numbers $a$ and $b$?
2. If the above question is positive, it is known if is possible to represent $\pi$ with the form $\left(\sqrt[n]{m}\right)^{\sqrt[p]{q}}$, for integers $n,m,p,q$?

Comment: I am guessing that this is unknown, but I'll just note that the answer is probably no, as there are only countably infinite many numbers of the form $a^b$ for $a$, $b$ algebraic.

Comment: As to your question, why do you think the algebraic numbers aren't closed under exponentiation?

Comment: Probably nobody can answer this question for *sure* (and if some body can, s/he won't do it for *free*), but you can bet for the answer 'no'.

Comment: IOW, do you have a counterexample? If so, you might want to include it in your question. This would make it better.

Comment: @Allawonder $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$ is known to be transcendental, I believe.

Comment: @Allawonder Gelfond-Schneider's theorem.

Comment: Yep: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem says that if $a\neq 0,1$ and $b$ irrational with both algebraic, then $a^b$ is transcendental.