# Can you obtain $\pi$ using elements of $\mathbb{N}$, and finite number of basic arithmetic operations + exponentiation?

Tags: number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

Is it possible to obtain $\pi$ from finite amount of operations
$\{+,-,\cdot,\div,\wedge\}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}$, the answer will still be the same)? Note that the set of all real numbers obtainable this way contains numbers that are not algebraic (for example $2^{2^{1/2}}$ is transcendental).

Bonus: If it happens that the answer is no, is it a solution to some equation generated that way (those $5$ operations performed finitely many times on elements on $\mathbb{N}$) ?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611084/is-it-possible-to-express-pi-as-ab-for-a-and-b-non-transcendental-numb

Comment: (this one is more general. If the answer to this one is "no" then the answer to the other one is "no" as well)

Comment: Of course not, but I can't prove it.  There are only countably many finite expressions of this sort, so you can only express countably many real numbers this way.  Unless a real has some reason to be expressible it almost certainly can't be.

Comment: Yes, there are only countably many of them, so most real numbers do not fall into this category. Still, not much can be deduced about any specific number from that fact. π is arguably somewhat special.

Comment: Could Machin-like formulas be of any use?

Comment: It can be obtained using calculus, check Wikipedia.

Comment: If you only use +,-,x,/, you can't get $\pi$ because it will only yield a rational number, so you have to use the exponential operator sometime.

Comment: The bonus question is the same question except allowing the use of $\log$, since all the operations are invertible, and their inverse is included in the allowed operations - except for $^$, which needs $\log$.

Comment: As mentioned above, it is probably false, but a disproof is difficult. A hope could be to describe a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$ containing all elements generated by the method you describe, but not containing $\pi$. How such a field would look is difficult to imagine though.