# Geometric Interpretations of $\frac{\pi^3}{12}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, area

If $n$ is a non zero positive number I write $K^{1/n}$ for the [disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics)) centered at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with radius $1/n.$ I construct an infinite arrangement of concentric discs centered at the origin using $K^{1/n}$ for each $n.$ I denote this arrangement by $BK.$ I set $A_{BK}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\text{area}(K^{1/n}).$ I  believe I have correctly that:

\begin{align}
A_{BK}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\text{area}(K^{1/n})\\
&=\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^2\\
&=\pi\eta(2)\\
&=\frac{\pi^3}{12}
\end{align}

where $\eta$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function). $A_{BK}$ is the infinite analogue of the "area between two discs" and so geometrically we can think of ${\pi^3 \above 1.5pt 12}$ as the "**area between infinitely many discs.**"

> ***Questions:*** Can we construct an integral (possibly a multiple integral) to calculate $A_{BK}$ ?

The picture below should help. We are adding up the red shaded areas.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something as simple as $\pi \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x+1)}{x} \, dx$ along with some geometric construction?

Comment: I believe I am missing something. If we have *concentric* disks, isn't the area of their union equal to the area of the  larger disk? What do you mean by *arrangement*?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - No. I am computing the area "between" concentric discs. I am deliberately defining $A_{BK}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\text{area}(K^{1/n}).$

Comment: @EricTowers yes I did. For example $K^{1/4}$ would be a disc with a radius equal to $1/4$ and so $\text{area}(K^{1/4})=\frac{\pi}{4^2}=\frac{\pi}{16}.$ I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: The picture you have is a bit misleading, since the bands of light and dark are evenly spaced.  What you should really have (according to the sum) is a solid band for $r = [1/2, 1]$;  a light band for $[1/3, 1/2]$;  a solid band for $[1/4, 1/3]$;  and so on.  In other words, the solid bands should get smaller towards the center.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  It's not drawn to scale.

Comment: Here's a [scale drawing](https://imgur.com/33f33lj) if you want one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest thing to do would be to write
$$
f(r) = \begin{cases} 1 & \lfloor 1/r \rfloor \text{ odd} \\ 0 & \lfloor 1/r \rfloor \text{ even} \end{cases}.
$$
This function is equal to 1 on $(1/2,1/2]$, equal to 0 on $(1/3, 1/2]$, equal to 1 on $(1/4,1/3]$, and so forth.  The area of your bullseye is then
$$
A = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 f(r) r \, dr \, d\theta =  2 \pi  \int_0^1 f(r) r \, dr .
$$

Now, we also know that the square wave function (oscillating between -1 and 1, with period 1) is given by a Fourier sine series:
$$
\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin (2 \pi (2k - 1) x)}{2k - 1}
$$
So one could try writing $f(r)$ in terms of this series:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin (\pi (2k - 1)/ x)}{2k - 1}.
$$
The area then becomes
$$
A = 2 \pi \left[\frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (\pi (2k - 1)/ r)}{2k - 1} r \, dr \right]\\
$$
But since the partial sums here obey the conditions of the dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$
A = \frac{\pi^3}{12} = \frac{\pi}{2} - 4 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\sin (\pi (2k - 1)/ r)}{2k - 1} r \, dr 
$$
or
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\sin (\pi (2k - 1)/ r)}{2k - 1} r \, dr = \frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{\pi^3}{48},
$$
which is not a result I would have expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since by the (inverse) Laplace transform
$$ \frac{1}{n^2} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x e^{-nx}\,dx $$
$\eta(2)$ admits the following integral representation
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1} x e^{-nx}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{e^x+1}\,dx\stackrel{x\mapsto -\log u}{=}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log u}{1+u}\,du$$
which is turned into $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+u)}{u}\,du$ by integration by parts. There are a good number of (equivalent) alternatives provided by Fourier or Fourier-Legendre series.

Comment: Sure what you have written is direct substitution of $\eta(2)$ and it requires multiplication by $\pi$ to get the desired result. I am trying to take advantage of the geometric construction itself to construct a new integral that computes $\frac{\pi^3}{12}.$

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: in such a case you may have a look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas)