# Real part of elliptic integral

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

Suppose complete elliptic integral of the first kind:
$$
\tag 1 K(k) \equiv \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^{2}(x)}}.
$$
I need to evaluate its real part on interval $0 < k < \infty$.

Since $K(k)$ has discontinuity at $k = 1$ and acquires imaginary part, we need to use analytical continuation:
$$
\tag 2 K(k) = \frac{1}{k}\left(K\left(\frac{1}{k}\right) \pm i K\left( \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k^{2}}}\right)\right).
$$
The great surprise for me is that by using the relation
$$
K(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\right)
$$
for $K(k)$ on the interval $0<k<1$ and for $\dfrac{1}{k}K\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)$ on the interval $1<k<\infty$, we find that expressions for $\mathrm{Re}K(k), 0 < k<1$ and $\mathrm{Re}K(k), 1 < k < \infty$ coincide:
$$
\mathrm{Re}K(k) = \frac{1}{k+1}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{k+1}\right). \quad 0 < k < \infty
$$
Why this is true? I didn't expect this because of singularity of $K(k)$ at $k = 1$... For example, imaginary part in the region $0 < k < 1$ is zero, while in the region $1 < z < \infty$ it is non-zero with non-trivial functional dependence, making a jump at $z = 1$.

Is this somehow related to general properties of analytical continuation (which in our particular case is given by (2))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First note: the function is not "analytic" at $k=1$. The real part has a logarithmic divergence.
- Second note: it is quite natural that "jump" across the branch cut, just occurs in imaginary component. A similar observation follows for functions that are defined (on some part of the real axis) as real functions due to Schwarz reflection principle. E.g., you observe a similar behaviour for the elementary function $\log z$ on the (standard) branch cut along the negative real line.
- Note that you may make the real part more regular without removing the "jump" of the imaginary part across the branch cut. For that you can take a look at the family of functions
  $$z^m \log z$$
  with $m\geq 1$.
- Last note: in this context, the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) might help to guide your intuition. Given any real function $u(x)$, the Hilbert transform $v= H(u)$ provides another function such that $f_1(x) = u(x) +i v(x)$ is analytic in the upper half plane (thus is is an analytic continuation in the upper half plane). By Schwarz reflection principle $f_2(x) = u(x)-i v(x)$ is an analytic function on the lower half plane. If $v(x)=0$ for some interval along the real axis (given by the function $f(x)=u(x)$), then $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the analytical continuation of this function in the upper/lower half plane. In the region, where $v\neq 0$, they obviously just differ by an imaginary number.

Comment: Thank You!

Is the the property of "continuity" of the real part related to mirror symmetry of elliptic integrals, i.e., $K(\bar{z}) = \bar{K(z)}$ (similarly to a relation of "continuity" of real part of $ln (z)$ due to Schwartz reflection principle)?

Comment: I also don't understand how the Schwartz reflection principle is applied to the function which isn't real on real axis.

Comment: By the way, may I interpret Your answer in a following way? It is possible to argue the fact that the functional dependence of real part of $K(x)$ is the same for $0<x<1$ and $1<x<\infty$ because it has logarithmic singularity at $x = 1$, while the real part of the logarithm near its branching point is symmetric (i.e., $\text{Re }ln(x) = ln(|x|)$ for $x < 0$, which coincides with $\text{Re}ln(x) = ln(x)$ for $x>0$)?

Comment: @JohnTaylor: it is not symmetric on the whole real line. But you are right that the symmetry close to $x=1$ is due to the logarithmic singularity which is required to appear if the imaginary part shows a step function behavior.

Comment: By the word ''symmetric'' I meaned that the functional dependence is the same from the left and from the right. I.e., by arguing that near the singularity the logarithm provides the symmetry of functional dependence of the real part, and by using continuity of these functions from left and from right we can argue the ''symmetricity'' from the left and from the right on the whole region

Comment: @JohnTaylor I think the keyword is indeed "logarithmic". Elliptic integral is solves a 2nd order ODE. The solution basis may be formed from one solution regular at $1$ and another having logarithmic divergence. The jump of the logarithmic solution is again a solution of the same ODE but since the log jump is just a constant, the result cannot be other thing than solution regular at $1$.