# Identity for the real part of the elliptic integral of the first kind: references

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

Is there any reference providing a derivation or a statement of an identity
$$
\text{Re}\  \text{K}(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}\text{K}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\right), \quad 0 < x < \infty ,
$$
where 
$$
\text{K}(x) =\int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2(t)}}
$$
is the elliptic integral of the first kind?

Although this identity is simply derived (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252855/real-part-of-elliptic-integral)) and can be verified graphically (in Wolfram Mathematica), I can't find any reference in which it is stated. This is very strange, leading to worries about its correctness.

Comment: This is just the (ascending) Landen transformation.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician : for me it's very important to have a direct reference on the precise statement given in my question. Although it can be derived by using Landen transformation, I can't meet it in any books I've read.

Comment: I presumed you'd then be able to search for references like [this one](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=CDP1zxFJLucC&pg=PA65) or [this one](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/gausslandenmonthly.pdf) with the nudge.

Comment: @John Taylor Sorry I do not understand your question, You need a proof of the following identity?
$K(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\right)$

Comment: @DaríoA.Gutiérrez : No, I need the proof of the identity $\text{Re} K(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}K\left( \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x+1}\right)$, valid for all $0 <x < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

See Erdelyi et al., Higher Transcendental Functions, Vol II, p.319, Table 4, last entry. The book is available via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman_Manuscript_Project

Comment: Thank You! But it seems that it states a relation $\text{K}(k)$ to the desired expression only on the interval $0<k<1$, while for $1<k<\infty$ it isn't valid, and therefore the reference isn't enough. [:(].

Comment: @John, classically, people are mostly concerned with moduli in $[0,1)$, so theorems are often restricted to moduli in that interval. You need a preliminary application of the reciprocal or imaginary modulus transformations to treat moduli outside $[0,1)$.